# Caching web pages with high-frequently changing elements

Tags: caching, ehcache

What would be a good approach in general to cache a web page where most of the content living in a database almost never changes (e.g. description) but a little content changes high-frequently (e.g. stock items).

I want to keep the web page cached as long as possible. Would it be an option to get the dynamic content via AJAX request? Do better approaches exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could request the stock data from a separate URL and use JavaScript to insert it into the document. That way, the HTML/CSS/JS remains the same and can be cached. The stock information is loaded using JavaScript and it's not inserted into the HTML by the server.

You could create a URL that returns JSON for this purpose (and similarly for other information that you wish to include using JavaScript).

Comment: And if those urls are on heavy load by the users, e.g. you have 100 page views per second, you can use some in memory caching tools for stock prices, caching them even for a 5 seconds (if viable) can make a huge difference in that scenario